# Check if a string contains a certain character

Tags: haskell

I need to check if my string contain a specific character.

I tried this:

```
charFound :: Char -> String -> Bool
charFound c s = filter(\x -> x == c) s
```

But it gives me:

> Couldn't match expected type `Bool` with actual type `[Char]`

I know that filter:

> returns a list constructed from members of a list (the second argument) fulfilling a condition given by the first argument.

How could I reach the goal and return a bool instead of a list?

Comment: Use the function `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` from the prelude.

Comment: See my updated answer for an easy way to implement this function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your purpose, you could use the function `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` from prelude. It does exactly what it says on the label. To implement this function, I would use something like this:

```
elem = any . (==)
```

or even more elementary:

```
elem x = foldr ((||) . (x ==)) False
```

Notice that due to the short-circuit behaviour of `(||)` this also works with infinite lists as long as `x` is found.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did (I'm noob on Haskell). What I did was `charFound c s = c elem s` and worked ;s

Comment: Your text came out a bit garbled but you can basically implement `charFound` as `charFound c s = elem c s` or even `charFound = elem`.

Answer (score 7):

The type of `filter` is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`.

You have supplied the first argument which has type `Char -> Bool` (which is correct), then the second argument which is `String` (that's `[Char]`) which is correct, so the type of `filter (\x -> x == c) s` is `[Char]`.

But the type signature you have provided says the function returns a `Bool`, which doesn't match the actual type returned.

You probably want to use `any` instead of `filter`. It's type is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`.

---

There's also an `all` function that returns `True` if and only if all elements of the list satisfy the predicate passed. You may also consider the functions `or` and `and` that given a `[Bool]` compute the disjunction or conjunction of the values. So `any f = or . map f` and `all f = and . map f`.

For all list-related functions see the [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html) module.